# using php to build map grid string

Tags: php, string, data-structures, while-loop

I'm using pp3Diso to build a game map. The library uses a string to determine the image to use in each grid cell like this: `01,01,01,01,01,01,01:02,01,01,01,01,01,01:01,01,01,01,01,01,01:01,01,01,01,01,01,01:01,01,01,01,01,01,01:01,01,01,01,01,01,01`.
I'm trying to piece together this type of string in PHP with while loops, but the code seems to just stop after the first iteration (`01,01,01,01,01,01,01,01:`). How can I get the code below to create the full string?

```
$mapStr = '';

$x = 1;
$y = 1;

while($x <= 500){
    while($y <= 500){
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.CITIES.' WHERE city_x = '.$x.' AND city_y = '.$y;
        $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
        $city = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);

        if($city){
            $mapStr .= '02'.(($x < 500) ? ',' : '');
        }else{
            $mapStr .= '01'.(($x < 500) ? ',' : '');
        }

        $y++;
    }

    if($x == 500){
        $mapStr .= ':';
    }else if($x == 500 && $y == 500){
        $mapStr .= '';
    }

    $x++;
}

$return['map'] = $mapStr;
```

Also, is there a more efficient way of doing this instead of querying the database for each cell?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out easier to do it in a `for` loop:

```
$columns = 501;
$rows = 501;

for($x = 1; $x < $columns; $x++){
    for($y = 1; $y < $rows; $y++){
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.CITIES.' WHERE city_x = '.$x.' AND city_y = '.$y;
        $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
        $city = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);

        if($city){
            $mapStr .= '02';
        }else{
            $mapStr .= '01';
        }

        if($y < 500){
            $mapStr .= ',';
        }elseif($y == 500){
            $mapStr .= ':<br />';
        }
    }

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.CITIES.' WHERE city_x = '.$x.' AND city_y = '.$y;
    $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
    $city = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);

    if($city){
        $mapStr .= '02';
    }else{
        $mapStr .= '01';
    }

    if($y < 500){
        $mapStr .= ',';
    }elseif($y == 500){
        $mapStr .= ':<br />';
    }
}
echo $mapStr;
```